# admin showing Please enter email address in config

Tags: admin, error, email

My Magento Admin showing this error Please enter email address in config
I don,t know where should i update the email to hide this error

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This does not look like a magento default error. I guess it relates to an extension you have installed.

Most extensions put their configuration settings somewhere under `System -> Configuration`.